# How does adjoint operator show up in FOIL’ing an inner product?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, inner-products, adjoint-operators, adjoint-functors

I have seen expressions involving the inner product where the adjoint operator shows up, and I cannot figure out why/how the adjoint operator shows up.     For example, say I have a function $f$ like this:

$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}||Ax-b||^2$

When $x=x+\Delta x$ I have seen this rewritten as the following:

$f(x+\Delta x)=\frac{1}{2}||Ax-b||^2+<A^*(Ax-b),\Delta x>+\frac{1}{2}||A\Delta x||^2$

So, I tried to work this out myself to figure out how the self adjoint operator $A^*$ shows up in there, but I the closest I can get is the following:

1) I re-express it as $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}||Ax-b+A\Delta x||^2$

2) Then take the square expansion (FOIL):

$f(x+\Delta x)=\frac{1}{2}||Ax-b||^2+<Ax-b,A\Delta x>+\frac{1}{2}<A\Delta x, A\Delta x>$

But now from here I do not see how we can get a self-adjoint operator to show up.  The closest that I can get, is if I use the property of conjugate symmetry (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Elementary_properties)

which gets me $<Ax-b, A\Delta x>=A^*<Ax-b, \Delta x>$, which is close, but doesn't quite achieve this : $f(x+\Delta x)=\frac{1}{2}||Ax-b||^2+<A^*(Ax-b),\Delta x>+\frac{1}{2}||A\Delta x||^2$.

How do I achieve that expression?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume we are working with a symmetric inner product over a real
vector space.

Consider
$$\|Au+v\|^2.$$
This equals
$$\left<Au+v,Au+v\right>
=\left<Au,Au\right>+\left<Au,v\right>+\left<v,Au\right>
+\left<v,Au\right>$$
since the inner product is additive in both arguments. By symmetry, this is
$$\|A u\|^2+2\left<v,Au\right>
+\|v\|^2$$
and by adjointness this is
$$\|A u\|^2+2\left<A^*v,u\right>+\|v\|^2.$$

In your application, take $v=Ax-b$ and $u=\Delta x$.

For complex inner product spaces and Hermitian inner products
one gets a somewhat different outcome.